# Multiple JS load and execution in a feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, feed

I have the following code:

```
$('.replay_text').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        pid = $(this).attr('postid');
        addCom('tix_'+pid);
        return false;
     }
     });
```

Which adds a comment each time I enter text in a specific textarea. The problem is that I need to include this JS multiple times on a page (I am loading a feed with content) so as I scroll down it's loaded 2-3 times. What happens is that once I enter a comment and submit it, it's added 2-3 times (the number of times it was loaded).

If I only load it once it won't work for the other feed content that is loaded dynamically (appended via jQuery).

Is there any solution for this problem? I tried including the JS once on top of the document but then it doesn't work at all, NOTE: all the feed content is loaded dynamically.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegated event. Then you can attach the handler once, and it will work for all elements appended dynamically:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.replay_text', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        pid = $(this).attr('postid');
        addCom('tix_'+pid);
        return false;
     }
 });
```

Comment: heh you are amazing. That solved my issue. I have another small problem - if you know how I could fix it - if I send "?" via the AJAX post it returns a strange string "jQuery17012417592667043209_1400787862383", do you know why this happens? Thank you a lot again